# Concat two strings together

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming, concatenation, string-concatenation

I want to define my own infix operator using Haskell that concats two strings together. However, I want to throw in an extra clause where the operator will concat over the overlapping elements in both strings. So an example would be

```
"eagle" myinfix "eagleeyes" = "eagleeyes"
"water" myinfix "book" = "waterbook"
"need" myinfix "education" = "needucation"
```

I already figured out how to return the overlapping portions in the strings with:

```
check x y = head $ filter (`isPrefixOf` y) (tails x)
```

But I don't know how to incorporate that in. Any help?

Comment: Why isn't the third example `"needucation"`?

Comment: And why isn't the first example `"eagleeyes"`? `check "eagle" "eagleeyes" = "eagle"`.

Comment: yeah sorry guys i realized i made some errors in the example outputs. I have corrected that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going about it in slightly the wrong way.

```
(+++) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
xs     +++ ys | xs `isPrefixOf` ys = ys
(x:xs) +++ ys                      = x : (xs +++ ys)
```

That is, you don't really care what the overlap is, you just care whether you have reached it.

---

Here's another solution without the explicit recursion.

```
(++++) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
xs ++++ ys = prefix ++ ys
  where (prefix, _) : _ = filter (\(_, overlap) -> overlap `isPrefixOf` ys) $ zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Here we go about finding the overlap, as in your `check`, but instead of keeping the overlap, we yield the portion of `xs` that *doesn't* overlap.

Comment: Another one using the Data.List.stripPrefix function: xs +++++ ys = xs ++ head [suffix | Just suffix <- map (flip stripPrefix ys) (tails xs)]

Answer (score 1):

```
overlapConcat :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
overlapConcat s t = s ++ drop (length $ check s t) t
```

This won't be as fast as the other versions provided since it will perform two passes over s, but I think it is more readable, and makes intuitive sense.